how do i evaluate this infinite sum?
hey I'm really confused on how to do infinite sums and how they work. this is one of the questions that i got. any help would be much appreciated:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n = \frac{p}{q}$$ $$n\in \mathbb{N}$$ $$p,q\in \mathbb{N}$$ for
$$x_1=\frac{16}{35}$$
and
$$x_{n+1}=\frac{-x_n^2}{1+x_n+x_n^2}$$
the original question asks what p + q is (both are relatively prime, forgot to add that) but i just wanna know how to evaluate the sum.
Again thanks.

Have you tried evaluating $x_2,x_3,\dotsc$ to see if there's a pattern to the terms or to the partial sum?

Are you aware that $x_{n+1} = \frac{{x_n}^2-{x_n}^3}{{x_n}^3-1}$ (or something like that)?

It appears that $p + q = 2 \times 16 + 35 = 67$. More generally, if $x_1 = a / b$ then $p / q = a / (a + b)$.

@Jean yes that is the correct answer. but how does it work tho? is there like a theorem im unaware of?

So Jean is claiming that if $f(x)=-\frac{x^2}{1+x+x^2}$ and $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$ then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_n=x_1/(1+x_1).$ (probably for $0<x_1<1)$ The special case where $x_1$ is rational does not seem important. This is a very surprizing result, and I long for its proof.

Excuse me as it's out of context, but still, can you please tell me from where have you got this problem? Actually I like to try out problems like these, but I don't generally encounter such problems. If you could tell me the resource(s) from where you got this problem, it would help me a lot in my mathematical career. Thanks!

@LetacGérard - The first question to ask is if the sum even converges. Note that if $x_1 = 1$, then it would not, as every term but the first would be $-1$. I have not checked further, but as this is wildly divergent, I doubt other values close enough to $1$ would converge either.

@FKcosθ it's a highschool level olympiad question from indonesia

Have you tried my suggestion, ssecnir? Have you tried ANYTHING? Please meet us halfway.

@GerryMyerson i have tried and there doesn't seem to be a pattern. i tried to use the infinite geometric sum thing and it didnt work out

@PaulSinclair If $x_1 = 1$ then $x_2 = -1/3 \neq -1$ and the sum does converge to $1/2$. However, if $x_1 = -1$ then $x$ is stationary and the sum diverges.

@ssecnirPmooDcitanuL you can show that $\forall |z| < 1, z - f(z) = \tilde{z} - f(\tilde{z})$ where $f$ is the sum for $x_1 = z$ and $\tilde{z} = -z/(1 + z)$.

@Jean - yes. I don't quite recall why I thought $1$ worked,

@abomasnow I believe otherwise, that the formula Letac wrote is indeed true, notably for all real $x > -1$.
